# Библиотека bootstrap пропала из проекта intellj idea, где она уже была подгружена

Tags: java, css, spring, bootstrap

Возможно, вопрос покажется глупым, но ответа в паутине я не нашел и сломал голову.

Писал небольшой проект по курсу Spring Boot на ютубе, внезапно (какое-то время все работало) пропал auto-complete bootstrap-a, и вместе с тем из External Libraries исчез bootstrap вместе с jQuery. Работаю с шаблонизатором FreeMarker.

На прикрепленном изображении код шаблона с head-ом, где я подгружаю библиотеки. Ctrl+Click по ссылкам выдает содержимое css и js файлов корректно, однако попытка написать код с автозаполнением, к примеру слово container в `<div class = "container">`, будет неудачной. Из External Libraries как раз исчез bootstrap, хотя он там был. Однако, сам сайт работает корректно, все элементы подгружены.

При создании нового проекта такая же проблема...

На втором изображении отражена подгрузка всех необходимых ресурсов css и js на страницу сайта.
Возможно, что-то сбилось в настройках самой Intellij, но может сам где накосячил...

[image: О]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо за ответы.
PS. Не ругайтесь за столь плохое оформление вопроса, первый раз задаю вопрос на StackOverflow, надеюсь на ваше понимание :)

Comment: Приведите пример кода и объясните что не работает, какая ошибка. Из того, что вы тут написали никто ничего не поймет.

Comment: @Roman, спасибо Вам за комментарий, на будущее учту, что нужно описывать проблему подробнее.
Дело было не в коде. Сбились настройки среды, не загружался bootstrap в идею.
Решил вопрос сам, понял, что недостаточно хорошо искал.
Решением моей проблемы было Settings -> Languages&Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries -> галочка на bootstrap.
Почему-то идея решила устроить мне весёлую жизнь и сама сбросила библиотеку..)